# Loading JavaScript in view in Ruby on Rails

Tags: javascript, jquery, ruby-on-rails, view

I want to use view specific JavaScript in Ruby on Rails 4.2.0 so I wanted to load it dynamically wherever I want to load it. I put the the javascript file which should be loaded(headers.js) in assets/javascripts. I removed the require tree line in the application.js file.

I have updated application.html.erb

**application.html.erb**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
   <head>
      <title>Sandbox</title>
      <%= stylesheet_link_tag    'application', media: 'all', 'data-turbolinks-track' => true %>
      <%= stylesheet_link_tag params[:controller] %>
      <%= csrf_meta_tags %>
      <%= render 'partials/shim' %>
   </head>
   <body>
      <%= render 'partials/header' %>
      <%= yield :javascript_includes %>
      <%= render 'partials/footer' %>
      <%= javascript_include_tag 'application', 'data-turbolinks-track' => true %>
   </body>
</html>
```

and I wanted to call the javascript file on the very top of the view.

**view.html.erb**

```
<% content_for :javascript_includes do %>
  <%= javascript_include_tag "headers.js" %>
<% end %>
```

I have updated the initializers/**assets.rb** file as well:

```
Rails.application.config.assets.precompile += %w( headers.js )
```

For some reason the html content of the view will not load and I'm getting an error in the console: Uncaught ReferenceError: jQuery is not defined.

**Why it does not work? How I can make this work and what am I missing?**

Comment: Maybe your file depends on jQuery, and you're trying to load it before Rails loads jQuery, you'll need to see if changing the order of assets make it work.

Comment: Try just `<%= javascript_include_tag "headers.js" %>` and restart your server, what do you get?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead passing `javascript_includes` to `yield`, try just requiring your needed javascript file wherever you want directly in the view, something like:

```
<%= javascript_include_tag "headers.js" %>
  <div class="vertical-center">
    ...
```

Your `body` in application.html.erb just like:

```
<%= render 'partials/header' %>
<%= yield %>
<%= render 'partials/footer' %>
```

And you could move the `application.js` file to the top, in order to preserve the Rails "structure":

```
<%= stylesheet_link_tag    'application', media: 'all', 'data-turbolinks-track' => true %>
<%= javascript_include_tag 'application', 'data-turbolinks-track' => true %>
...
```

Answer (score 0):

This should work:

Add in view

```
<% content_for(:head) do %>
  <%= javascript_include_tag 'headers.js' %>
<% end %>
```

And in initializers/assets.rb

```
Rails.application.config.assets.precompile += %w( headers.js )
```